# In listings, lines that are broken (option breaklines enabled) cause frame to be drawn badly. How do you fix this?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, framed

I have an `lstlisting` which has `breaklines` and `frame` enabled. The actual setting is as follows.

```
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle={},
    frame=single,
    frameround=tttt,
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
    escapechar=\&
}
```

The problem is, whenever a line is too long and thus breaks into two, the frame around it doesn't include the second line. Here is an image of how it looks like:

[image: Broken frame around lstlisting]

**Edit**: Alright, I found out that I was missing some important information. I am styling the listing myself (as opposed to automatically) as you can see in the image. That is why I use `&` as `escapechar` and practically all of the contents of the listing is escaped. See this code (note that this is software generated!):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}

\lstset{
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        keywordstyle={},
        frame=single,
        frameround=tttt,
        rulecolor=\color{gray},
        escapechar=\&
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
&\#include <stdio.h>&
&int main()&
&\{&
        &\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.2,0.4}{printf("Enter a, b, and c (space separated) in the following equation:\textbackslash{}nax\^{}2+bx+c = 0\textbackslash{}n");}&
        &\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.2,0.4}{scanf("\%f \%f \%f", \&a, \&b, \&c);}&
        &\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.2,0.4}{printf("What happens when I type two less{-}than signs like this? << \textbackslash{}n");}&
&\}&
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

In this code, I just used `\textcolor` for demonstration, although that IS principally what I am doing.

This code produces this output:

[image]

This is `pdflatex`'s output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2009-06-19, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, hungarian,
 icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, marathi, or
iya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kurmanji,
 lao, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk, pol
ish, portuguese, romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spani
sh, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/home/sciabaz/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)) (./a.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/cmtt/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbraceleft' on input line 19.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./a.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )</usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb></
usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/latxfont/lcircle1
.pfb>
Output written on a.pdf (1 page, 34186 bytes).
Transcript written on a.log.
```

Note that with Mike's code, I didn't get the font warning.

Comment: As a quick side question, how do I prevent latex from converting `<<` to a single character? I don't know how the proper english words are to be able to search for it!

Comment: Answer to my previous commen: I used `<{}<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that since the multiple lines are produces while you are escaped to LaTeX, the `lstlisting` environment does not get a chance to add the vertical rule on the left and right hand side.

One simple way around this would be to use some other tool to actually put the frame around the code. Here is an example of using an `mdframed` environment (but any other alternate should work just as well) to produce:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\lstset{
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        keywordstyle={},
        frame=none,%              changed to "none"
        %frameround=tttt,%        commented as not relevant with frame=none
        rulecolor=\color{gray},
        escapechar=\&
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=5pt]
\begin{lstlisting}
&\#include <stdio.h>&
&int main()&
&\{&
        &\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.2,0.4}{printf("Enter a, b, and c (space separated) in the following equation:\textbackslash{}nax\^{}2+bx+c = 0\textbackslash{}n");}&
        &\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.2,0.4}{scanf("\%f \%f \%f", \&a, \&b, \&c);}&
        &\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.2,0.4}{printf("What happens when I type two less{-}than signs like this? << \textbackslash{}n");}&
&\}&
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That was what I thought also. But good to know there is a workaround for this. I will give it a shot and let you know

Comment: Apparently the package `mdframed` is much changed from TeXLive 2010 to TeXLive 2011. I installed 2011 and it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not able to reproduce either of your questions with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{red},
    frame=single,
    frameround=tttt,
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Enter a, b, and c (space separated) in the following equation:\nax^2+bx+c = 0\n");
  scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
  printf("What happens when I type two less-than signs like this? <<\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you get the same results using my code? If not, what TeX distribution are you using? If so, can you provide an alternate MWE that shows your problems?

EDIT:

I suspect the method you're using is going to cause a ton of extra work, and since I'm not sure what you're really trying to accomplish (why are you escaping out almost everywhere?), here's a second example -- the first part colors all identifiers the same way, the second part colors specific identifiers, and leaves others unformatted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    %keywordstyle=\color{red},
    %identifierstyle=\color{blue},
    %stringstyle=\color{green},
    frame=single,
    frameround=tttt,
    rulecolor=\color{gray},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,identifierstyle=\color{blue},caption={highlight all identifiers}]
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float a, b, c;
  printf("Enter a, b, and c (space separated) in the following equation:\nax^2+bx+c = 0\n");
  scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
  printf("What happens when I type two less-than signs like this? <<\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,
  emph={printf},emphstyle=\color{blue},
  emph={[2]{scanf}},emphstyle={[2]\color{magenta}},
  caption={highlight specific words}
]
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float a, b, c;
  printf("Enter a, b, and c (space separated) in the following equation:\nax^2+bx+c = 0\n");
  scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);
  printf("What happens when I type two less-than signs like this? <<\n");
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: indeed, I had missed a key information in my question. Please see my edit.

Comment: Made a second example set. What are you really trying to do here? I suspect there has to be a better way than manually coloring various line of code.

Comment: Mike, you are right. Normally, I wouldn't do such a crazy thing! However, I'm not writing the latex code manually. I have written a program taking input similar to markdown, with some added stuff (more to come) mainly to create code documentation. The output are both html and latex. As far as the program is concerned, it is MUCH easier to escape everything, than try to understand what to escape and what not.

Comment: If you are interested in my program by the way, you can find it [here](http://github.com/ShabbyX/DocThis)

Comment: And the reason listings options don't work for me is that, I'm not highlighting specific keywords. I don't even care what language the code is written in, or even if it is written in a language. I color parts of the text as is dictated by the writer of the documentation source file. The main reason for highlighting is to direct attention of reader to a specific important command, or part of the text, rather than highlighting code for overall readability.

Comment: Replace my "manually coloring various lines of code" with "having a program color various lines of code". The first example given may indicate some bugs in your existing parser, assuming everything is supposed to be consistent, or else I totally misunderstand the styling: one if statement is black, another not. One set of format specifiers in a printf are colored differently than the surrounding string, another set isn't. One set of printf variables are colored lighter than an equivalent set on another printf statement. Short form: why not let `listings` do the work? What's missing from it?

Comment: For example, you are writing a piece of code for the user as an example in your documentation. You have this line of code: `printf("%s: This is the value you get: %d\n", prefix, someObject.function(&param));` You want to direct the attention of the reader to the fact that the output of `someObject::function` is printed using `%d` and the way to call the function is as written in the last argument of `printf`. What you would do then would be to highlight `%d` and `someObject.function(&param)`

Comment: There is nothing regular about it, nothing that can be generalized. It is just that you want to mark a part of the listing to be highlight for whatever reason you have.

Comment: Think about it like this: right now that I am writing this comment, whenever I want to mark something as code, I enclose it with `\``, right? You can't put a rule on where I write `\`` so that stackoverflow would automatically change the font of parts of my comment. I am doing the same with user's listings. Where they ask for it, I highlight their text.